# How to click on "Add" when adding a ticket to apple wallet?

Tags: react-native, acceptance-testing, detox

Using detox 13.3.1 I am working on writing an acceptance test for this feature in a react-native app. The feature includes adding a ticket to the wallet in which detox test cannot tap on anything once the wallet screen comes up.

I tried `by.text` and simply query the button text "Add" but it doesn't get it. Also, `tapAtPoint` doesn't tap anywhere as well. However, I don't know the type of "Add" button.

Comment: Most likely, the Wallet interface is rendered off-process, and so Detox cannot interact with the elements. I suggest you mock the Wallet API so that you can continue with your tests.

Comment: However, it works fine on image uploader. I was looking for a way to just tap anywhere on the screen where I can just play with coordinates to make a tap on add.